# Optimizing custom template tag which makes API call

Tags: django

I have this template tag which works well but when I use it many times in template whole page loads too long. How can I improve this?

```
@register.simple_tag
def converted_currency(amount, currency, default_user_currency, date=timezone.now()):
    c = CurrencyConverter('http://www.ecb.int/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-hist.zip', fallback_on_wrong_date=True, fallback_on_missing_rate=True)
    converted_value = c.convert(amount, currency, default_user_currency, date=date)
    return Decimal(converted_value).quantize(Decimal("0.00"))
```

Used library: https://pypi.org/project/CurrencyConverter/

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/cache/#the-low-level-cache-api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make `CurrencyConverter` once and all template tag calls use this instance

see below:

```
currency_converter = CurrencyConverter('http://www.ecb.int/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-hist.zip', 
                                       fallback_on_wrong_date=True,
                                       fallback_on_missing_rate=True)

...

@register.simple_tag
def converted_currency(amount, currency, default_user_currency, date=timezone.now()):
    converted_value = c.convert(amount, currency, default_user_currency, date=date)
    return Decimal(converted_value).quantize(Decimal("0.00"))
```

you can also set expire time on it and refresh instance when instance expires